# TypeError: jQuery(...) is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

In a MVC 4 project I'm trying to test a jquery slider that i want to use. This is how the head section of my page looks like:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link href="~/slider/bannerscollection_zoominout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- must have -->
       
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
    </style>




    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/slider/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/slider/js/bannerscollection_zoominout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- must have -->




    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        if (ua.indexOf("msie") != -1 || ua.indexOf("opera") != -1) {
            jQuery('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            jQuery('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        }

        jQuery(function () {
            jQuery('#bannerscollection_zoominout_opportune').bannerscollection_zoominout({
                skin: 'opportune',
                responsive: true,
                width: 1920,
                height: 1200,
                fadeSlides: true,
                width100Proc: true,
                height100Proc: true,
                showNavArrows: true,
                showBottomNav: true,
                autoHideBottomNav: true,
                thumbsWrapperMarginTop: -55,
                pauseOnMouseOver: false
            });

        });


    </script>
```

I'm getting the error: TypeError: jQuery(...).bannerscollection_zoominout is not a function

I searched and tried a lot of suggestion, but no success. Some help with this will be great!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that the only error that you are seeing in the console?

Comment: yes, but when i click on 'All' in firebug console, i see also :[18:40:03 GMT+0200] Browser Link: Exception thrown in callback method setPixelPusingMode: SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
browserLink (line 64)
2
[18:40:03 GMT+0200] Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback:
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

Comment: You should be getting at least another error, prior to the "TypeError: jQuery(...).bannerscollection_zoominout..." one, that will tell you one of these 2 things: a) bannerscollection_zoominout.js could not be found in that location; or b) there was an error in the code in bannerscollection_zoominout.js and it didn't load. If you are not getting it, then open the bannerscollection_zoominout.js file and double check that the name of the function is actually bannerscollection_zoominout  and not something different (remember that JavaScript is case sensitive)

Comment: I do not get other errors. and yes the function exist. In a non asp.net mvc project(just html, css and js)it works. Only in mvc i get this. when opening the page in ie, i get :Object doesn't support property or method 'bannerscollection_zoominout'

Comment: the problem was that the jquery was called twice..solved!